# Unique Pointer as default parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to give the nullpointer wrapped as a unique pointer as the default argument to a function. Using only pointers the header might look like this

```
double f(A* vec = nullptr);
```

Since I do however need to use a unique_ptr, I tried to change it to

```
double f(std::unique_ptr<A>& A vec = nullptr);
```

or

```
double f(std::unique_ptr<A>& A vec = std::unique_ptr<A>(nullptr));
```

Which results in the errors

> could not convert ‘nullptr’ from ‘std::nullptr_t’ to ‘std::unique_ptr&’

and

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::unique_ptr&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::unique_ptr’

respecively. Is there a way to do this? I am relatively new to C++, so the answer might be obvious.

---

Not relevant to the question, but an explanation for my choice of unique_ptr: The parameter vec is used as the start value for an iteration in f and an improved value is returned with the pointer. The plan was that if no start value is given the pointer is set to the nullptr and a start value is calculated during the program. Since I however generate a new object, it would from all I can see be safer to use unique_ptr over a naked pointer.

Comment: Do you return value through `vec`?

Comment: How can you have a default value for a reference variable? What would it be a reference to?

Comment: I think it might be better to use overloading here, since there's extra logic in the parameter-less case.

Comment: You could store a const reference to a unique pointer, which would still allow you to access the raw pointer.

Comment: This is why I prefer to use dumb pointers as function parameters. You can always use `get` on the `unique_ptr` to get its internal pointer when you make the function call.

Comment: Can you explain if the function needs to own the pointer?

Comment: I strongly suspect you don't want a unique pointer here - that transfers ownership into the function.  I think you need to ask a new question explaining what you are *actually* trying to do.

Comment: The motivation for vec is given in the second text - ideally, I want to return an adjusted start value through vec.
@scohe001 - I do not care about the value of the default parameter, it would however allow me to check during the function whether vec.get()==nullptr and thus whether a start value was given.

Comment: @Jabor "I want to return an adjusted start value through vec." how did you do that through raw pointer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say you have two optione here.

**1)** The function does not *own* the pointer it merely uses it. In this case *pass a raw pointer* or (better) a *reference* (if nullptr is not an option).

```
// correct way to express a call to a non-owning function.
double f(A* vec = nullptr);
```

Calling code will use the function like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> vec;

f(vec.get()); // pass the raw pointer to the function
```

**2)** The function needs to manage the life of the pointer or reseat the pointer (own it) in which case accept a `std::unique_ptr` by **value**.

```
// way to express transfer of ownership to a function
double f(std::unique_ptr<A> vec = std::unique_ptr<A>());
```

There is really no need to accept a reference if the function needs to take ownership of the pointer.

In discussions a **third** option has presented itself.

**3)** The function is expected to *modify* the pointer if you pass one in *otherwise* it will use its own internal pointer.

This is unusual but you could do this with a pair of overloaded functions like this:

```
// way to express a function that modifies a smart pointer
// (for example reseating it)
double f(std::unique_ptr<A>& vec);

// version where the uses doesn't want to supply the pointer
// and doesn't care about the modified value.
double f() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> vec; // a dummy
    f(vec); // pass in the dummy
}
```

Comment: This transfers ownership but it is not clear if OP really wants this

Comment: @Slava I guess but who would own a default value otherwise?

Comment: OP tries to convert function with raw pointer and may not understand what implication would have to past `std::unique_ptr` by value, from raw pointer it is not clear if function takes ownership

Comment: @Slava But he doesn't pass the raw pointer by reference so I think he doesn't want to change the pointer.

Comment: @Slava : For new code, a raw pointer parameter is non-owning.  (There are complications when dealing with legacy code or C interfaces.)

Comment: As stated in comments OP does not want to transfer ownership and simply does not understand implications of passing it by value.

Comment: This solution works if I never want to use an argument (and thus always use the default parameter), but adding the argument results in copying the unique_ptr, which is not permited as far as I can see. I guess this could be fixed using a shared pointer though.

Comment: @Jabor Does the function just use the pointer or could it delete it or set it to point to something else?

Comment: @Galik - it checks whether or not the nullptr is given or not. If it is the nullptr, it overwrites it, in case it is not the nullptr it uses it.

Comment: @Jabor Is that change needed to be passed back out of the function to the caller?

Comment: @Galik - the changed Object pointed at by vec is needed, yes.

Comment: @Jabor It is needed *inside* the function, but do you want the pointer the caller passed it to be changed as well?

Comment: @Galik - I meant to add outside in the previous comment. Yes, it is needed inside and outside the function.

Comment: @Jabor So if you call the function **without** an argument the function will allocate the object. How is that change going to be reflected to the caller if they did not use a variable to call the function with?

Comment: @Galik - if the function is called without an argument, it is supposed to recognize this (since the pointer equals the nullptr) and generate an appropriate object (start value) itself and use it for further calculations. This object is then not returned to the caller of the function, but that is not a large problem.
In case an argument is given, the start value is supposed to be used, changed and then returned to the caller via the pointer.

Comment: @Jabor I have added an option for that as option #3.

Answer (score 3):

The second error is because you are binding a non-const reference to a rvalue (which it kind of says). If that is a must, you cannot use a default value, or use a const reference:

```
double f(const std::unique_ptr<A>& A vec = std::unique_ptr<A>(nullptr));
```

Comment: @MartinBonner I saw it and was going to write "hey, this still does not fix the binding error", but then it dissappeared:D

Answer (score 3):

```
double f(std::unique_ptr<A>& vec = nullptr);
```

doesn't work since the compiler has to create a temporary `std::unique_ptr` from `nullptr`. Had you used

```
double f(std::unique_ptr<A> const& vec = nullptr);
```

the compiler would have accepted it.

One work around is to overload.

```
double f(std::unique_ptr<A>& vec)
{
   return 0;
}

double f()
{
   std::unique_ptr<A> vec = nullptr;
   return f(vec);
}
```